# How to put a text on 2 lines and part of the text in bold?

Tags: user-interface, swiftui, interface

I'm new to SwiftUI and I'm looking to reproduce the image below. Here's my current code.

```
VStack(spacing: 6) {
    HStack {
        Text("Enter your email to sign in or create an")
            .font(.system(size: 18))

        Text("account.")
            .font(.system(size: 18))
            .bold()
    }
}
```

Figma model:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a good occasion to use Swift's native `AttributedString` with markdown.

Everything wrapped in `**` is displayed in bold.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 6) {
            Text("Welcome!")
                .font(.largeTitle).bold()
            HStack {
                Text(attributedPrompt)
                    .font(.system(size: 18.0))
                    .padding(.trailing, 100)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }

    
    var attributedPrompt : AttributedString {
        return try! AttributedString(markdown: "Enter your email to **sign in** or **create an account**.")
    }
}
```